# Why can't I append data to the list asynchronously with using threading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I use threading to append some number into the list, when I printed it out, I found that these numbers are sequential, that means it appended synchronously.

```
import threading

list_a = []

def append_data():
    global list_a
    for i in range(10):
        list_a.append(i+1)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=append_data)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=append_data)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()

#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(list_a)
```

However, if i add a print statement under the append function, the result is random.

```
import threading

list_a = []

def append_data():
    global list_a
    for i in range(10):
        list_a.append(i+1)
        print('...')

t1 = threading.Thread(target=append_data)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=append_data)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()

#random result ... [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(list_a)
```

May i know why this happened?
If i want to append/get data to/from the list asynchronously without print statement, how can i do that?
Thanks so much, sorry for poor english.

Comment: IO (i.e. printing) uses time. in your 1st case the 1st (or 2nd, who knows) thread is already finished before the other thread even starts doing things with the list. Beside that your example is trivial and nothing you need threading for. If you import random and sleep some random amount after each list_a.append you get mixed up results as well. The result is not random, it is in order of execution of the threads by the OS.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried it with a random sleep time and it's able to show a random result.